# undefined method `generators' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, guard, spork

I have `rspec2` installed with `spork` and `guard` and when run the `guard` command, I get this error:

```
undefined method `generators' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007fb3944b23b0> (NoMethodError)
/Users/amiterandole/Desktop/current/rails/depot/spec/spec_helper.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core.rb:108:in `configure'
/Users/amiterandole/Desktop/current/rails/depot/spec/spec_helper.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
/Users/amiterandole/Desktop/current/rails/depot/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:138:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in preload'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/app_framework.rb:49:in `preload'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:134:in `block in preload'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork.rb:62:in `exec_prefork'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:120:in `preload'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:25:in `preload'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/runner.rb:74:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/spork:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/spork:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb:35:in `block in shellsplit': Unmatched double quote: "--format RSpec::Instafail' > .rspec" (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb:33:in `scan'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb:33:in `shellsplit'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb:128:in `shellsplit'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:115:in `block in args_from_options_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:115:in `map'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:115:in `args_from_options_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `options_from'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:101:in `project_options'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:81:in `file_options'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:77:in `all_configs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:34:in `parse_options'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
14:48:19 - ERROR - Could not start Spork server for RSpec after 30 seconds. I will continue waiting for a further 60 seconds.

14:49:19 - ERROR - Could not start Spork server for RSpec. Make sure you can use it manually first.

14:49:19 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
14:49:19 - INFO - Running all specs
14:49:19 - ERROR - Guard::RSpec failed to achieve its <start>, exception was:
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] ArgumentError: Unmatched double quote: "--format RSpec::Instafail' > .rspec"
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb:35:in `block in shellsplit'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb:33:in `scan'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb:33:in `shellsplit'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb:128:in `shellsplit'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:115:in `block in args_from_options_file'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:115:in `map'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:115:in `args_from_options_file'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `options_from'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:101:in `project_options'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:81:in `file_options'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:77:in `all_configs'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:34:in `parse_options'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-rspec-2.3.3/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:59:in `parsed_or_default_formatter'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-rspec-2.3.3/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:79:in `rspec_arguments'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-rspec-2.3.3/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:119:in `run_via_drb'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-rspec-2.3.3/lib/guard/rspec/runner.rb:36:in `run'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-rspec-2.3.3/lib/guard/rspec.rb:35:in `run_all'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-rspec-2.3.3/lib/guard/rspec.rb:31:in `start'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:99:in `block in run_supervised_task'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:97:in `catch'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:97:in `run_supervised_task'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in run'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:175:in `block (3 levels) in scoped_guards'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:174:in `each'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:174:in `block (2 levels) in scoped_guards'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:173:in `catch'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:173:in `block in scoped_guards'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:172:in `each'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:172:in `scoped_guards'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:53:in `block in run'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/lumberjack-1.0.2/lib/lumberjack.rb:27:in `unit_of_work'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:52:in `run'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard.rb:187:in `block in start'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard.rb:363:in `block in within_preserved_state'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard.rb:360:in `within_preserved_state'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard.rb:185:in `start'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/lib/guard/cli.rb:110:in `start'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-1.6.0/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/guard:19:in `load'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/guard:19:in `<main>'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
> [#CFA8FD5ABE83] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
14:49:19 - INFO - Guard::RSpec has just been fired
14:49:21 - INFO - Bundle already up-to-date

14:49:21 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/amiterandole/Desktop/current/rails/depot'
```

If I take out the generators config, things seem to work just fine. I am using `rails 3.2.11` and `ruby-1.9.3-p194`

Here is what my gemfile looks like:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'meta_request', '0.2.1'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
    gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 3.3.0"
    gem "guard-rspec"
    gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2"
    gem "database_cleaner"
    gem "launchy", ">= 2.1.0"
    gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
    gem 'spork', '~> 1.0rc'
    gem 'guard-spork', '~> 1.0rc'
    gem "guard-bundler"
    gem "guard-migrate"
end
```

Here is my guardfile:

```
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/.+\.rb$})
end

guard 'rspec', :cli => "--drb" do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

Here is my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'database_cleaner'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # ## Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
    # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
    # the seed, which is printed after each run.
    #     --seed 1234
    config.order = "random"

    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

    config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
    config.filter_run :focus => true
    config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

    config.generators do |g|
      g.view_specs false
      g.helper_specs false
      g.test_framework :rspec, :fixture => true
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'
    end

end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  FactoryGirl.reload
end

end
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I found the error. Apparently the `config.generators` block goes inside `application.rb`:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.view_specs false
  g.helper_specs false
  g.test_framework :rspec, :fixture => true
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'
end
```